# Can't fetch data from Firestore SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I want to get data from a realtime database and display it on the screen. But no data is displayed.I gen only white screen without data.I think it might be because of the empty array, which is described in the console, but I don't know how to fix it. Please tell me what the problem is. Thank you!

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZJ7g.png)

[Firebase data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apWHl.png)

Model:

```
import Foundation

struct Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var description: String
    var test: String
    var boolean: Bool
    var number: Int
    var flowerURL: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case description
        case test
        case boolean
        case number
        case flowerURL
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class TestableViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Item]()
    
    private var database = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        database.collection("Some").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.items = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Item in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let description = data["Descriprion"] as? String ?? ""
                let test = data["Test"] as? String ?? ""
                let boolean = data["Test bool"] as? Bool ?? false
                let number = data["Test int"] as? Int ?? 0
                let flowerURL = data["flowerURL"] as? String ?? ""
                
                let labrador = Item(description: description, test: test, boolean: boolean, number: number, flowerURL: flowerURL)
                return labrador
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestableView: View {
    
   @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TestableViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.items) { item in
            Text("\(item.description)")
            Text("\(item.id)")
            Text("\(item.number)")
            Text("\(item.test)")
            Text("\(item.flowerURL)")
        }
    }
}

struct TestableView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestableView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using code from Firestore, which is different than the Realtime Database

Comment: @jnpdx , please tell me , how can I fix this issue? Change the Realtime Database?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write use the code for the Realtime Database instead of the Firestore code. Or, switch to Firestore, if you want to store your data there.